# Проверка текущего значения свойства "right" из JS

Tags: javascript

Элемент абсолютно позиционирован и имеет значение свойства `right: -1100px` установленное через CSS.
В момент некоего события (допустим клик по кнопке) ему присваивается CSS класс, в котором значение `right` установлено в `0` и, при помощи свойства `transition`, элемент начинает плавно двигаться.

*Вопрос*: Каким образом из **JavaScript** можно получить текущее значение свойства `right` во время движения от `-1100px` до `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вам следует использовать свойство **offsetLeft**.

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
    foo.setAttribute('class', 'to-right');
  setInterval(function() {
     
    document.getElementById('position').innerHTML = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetWidth - foo.offsetLeft - foo.offsetWidth
  }, 100);
  }
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  }

#foo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
  }

.to-right {
  right: 200px !important;
  transition: 5s
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="foo"></div>
</div>
<div>right: <span id="position"></span></div>

<button id="button">click</button>
```